# C : Get a segmentation fault when generating random maze

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, maze

I try to generate a maze randomly but I get a segmentation fault when compiling the program below

Here's the code

```
void spread(int v, int x, int y, int *t,int w, int *count){
    //table of directions(Right,Down,Left,Up)
    int d[4][2] = {{1,0},{0,1},{-1,0},{0,-1}}; 
    int i;
    t[y * w + x] = v;

    if(v == 0 && (x & 1) && (y & 1))
        (*count)++; /*increments at every box which has value as zero with x odd and y also*/

    //spread the value to all directions
    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        if(v < t[(y+d[i][1]) * w + x +d[i][0]]){
            spread(v,x + d[i][0],y+d[i][0],t,w,count);
        }
    }
}

int *init(int m, int n){
        //Initializing the maze
        int *t = NULL, mp = 2 * m +1, np = 2 * n + 1;
        int x,y,k,d;
        int count = 1;
        t = malloc(mp * np * sizeof *t);
        assert(t);
        for(y = k = 0; y < np ;++y){
            for(x = 0; x < mp; ++x){
                if((x & 1) && (y & 1))
                    t[y * mp + x] = k++;
                else
                    t[y * mp + x] = -1; 
            }

        }
        //Make a labyrinth randomly
        while(count < (m * n)){
            srand(time(NULL));
            if(myRand(2)){ // Up/Down separator 
                do{
                    x = myRand(m) * 2 + 1;
                    y = (myRand(n - 1) + 1) * 2;

                }while(t[(y - 1) * mp + x] == t[(y + 1) * mp + x]); /*Don't select the ones which are equal*/

                d = t[(y - 1) * mp + x] - t[(y + 1) * mp + x];
                //d selects the lowest one
                if(d > 0){
                    t[y * mp +x] = t[(y + 1) * mp + x];
                    spread(t[(y + 1) * mp +x],x,y-1,t,mp,&count);
                }

                else if(d < 0){
                    t[y * mp +x] = t[(y - 1) * mp + x];
                    spread(t[(y - 1) * mp +x],x,y+1,t,mp,&count);
                }   
            }
            else{   //Right/Left separator
                do{         
                    x = (myRand(m - 1) + 1) * 2;
                    y = myRand(n) * 2 + 1;

                }while(t[y * mp + x - 1] == t[y * mp + x + 1]);

                d = t[y * mp + x - 1] - t[y * mp + x + 1];

                if(d > 0){
                    t[y * mp +x] = t[y * mp + x + 1];
                    spread(t[y * mp + x + 1],x-1,y,t,mp,&count);
                }

                else if(d < 0){
                    t[y * mp +x] = t[y * mp +x - 1];
                    spread(t[y * mp + x - 1],x+1,y,t,mp,&count);
                }   
            }
        }   
        return t;
}
```

The labyrinth is initialized (which is t here) first with values: -1 for walls and v > 0 for the nodes

Then in order to make a connection between nodes( this in order to have a labyrinth), a box is chosen randomly but either the line or the column must be odd to select a wall which represents a separator(up/down or right/left)

So "d" takes the minimum between the boxes surrounding the wall(means the minimum between the value of the box above the wall and the value of the box below the wall , same thing with right/left)

The function spread: it spreads a value to all directions(right,down,left,up)

Here's an example of it:

```
+  +  +  +  +  +  +  +  +  
+  0  +  1  +  2  +  3  +  
+  +  +  +  +  +  +  +  +  
+  4  +  5  +  6  +  7  +  
+  +  +  +  +  +  +  +  +  
+  8  +  9  +  10 +  11 +  
+  +  +  +  +  +  +  +  +
```

when spreading some values to others

```
+  +  +  +  +  +  +  +  +  
+  0  +  1  1  1  +  3  +  
+  +  +  +  +  +  +  +  +  
+  4  +  5  +  6  +  7  +  
+  +  +  +  +  +  +  +  +  
+  8  +  9  9  9  +  11 +  
+  +  +  +  +  +  +  +  +
```

I tried to solve the problem by debugging the program, it works for a moment I mean displaying what's above but then I got this

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000000004008e4 in spread (
   v=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x7fffff7fefec>, x=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x7fffff7fefe8>, 
    y=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x7fffff7fefe4>, t=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x7fffff7fefd8>, 
    w=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x7fffff7fefe0>, count=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x7fffff7fefd0>)
    at Lab.c:34
#1  0x0000000000400a1a in spread (v=8, x=4, y=6, t=0x603010, w=9, 
    count=0x7fffffffddd4) at Lab.c:48
#2  0x0000000000400a1a in spread (v=8, x=4, y=6, t=0x603010, w=9, 
    count=0x7fffffffddd4) at Lab.c:48
#3  0x0000000000400a1a in spread (v=8, x=4, y=6, t=0x603010, w=9, 
    count=0x7fffffffddd4) at Lab.c:48
#4  0x0000000000400a1a in spread (v=8, x=4, y=6, t=0x603010, w=9, 
    count=0x7fffffffddd4) at Lab.c:48
```

Comment: Suspect unbounded recursion

Comment: What guarantees `y * w + x` is in bounds for `t`?

Comment: x  can't exceed mp(the same for y can't exceed np) so I think that y * w + x can't also exceed the value of mp * np

Comment: Why do you think that it exceeds the limits of t

Comment: If i understood well, in the `spread` function, if `v != 0`, you skip the first `if` statement, and enter the `for` loop. Then if any block next to the current one (associated to the value `v`) is associated to a lesser or equal value than `v`, you enter the `spread` function with a new current block (next to the previous one). **BUT** since you don't evaluate the value of `x`, `y`, or `*count`, you may : or run out of the limits of the array, or also turn in rounds again and again until `Stack Overflow` occurs. (I'm absolutely not sure of what i say). Can someone tell if i'm right/wrong ?

Comment: In the "spread" function x and y change by adding a value from the tab d[4][2] (depending of the direction right/down/up/left)

Comment: Do you mean by not evaluating the value of x,y  cheking whether x and y exceed the bounds

Comment: Yes, you don't check if `x` and `y` are still in the bounds of `t`. I think this may cause a memory trouble.

Comment: But normally it cannot do you think that it occurs when calling the function "spread" in the loop of "for" (recursively)

Comment: I'm not sure at all, but it may occur, can you print out the values of `x` and `y` while executing the loop ?

Comment: Thank you all for your help, I realized that I've made a mistake after displaying the values of x and y(by applying the advise of Hollyol) and found that they have the same value so the line where the function spread is called recursively (in the loop after the if) is replaced by   : spread(v,x + d[i][0],y+d[i][1],t,w,count);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void spread(int v, int x, int y, int *t,int w, int *count){
    //table of directions(Right,Down,Left,Up)
    int d[4][2] = {{1,0},{0,1},{-1,0},{0,-1}}; 
    int i;
    t[y * w + x] = v;

    if(v == 0 && (x & 1) && (y & 1))
        (*count)++; /*increments at every box which has value as zero with x odd and y also*/

    //spread the value to all directions
    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        if(v < t[(y+d[i][1]) * w + x +d[i][0]]){
            spread(v,x + d[i][0],y+d[i][1],t,w,count);
        }
    }
}

int *init(int m, int n){
        //Initializing the maze
        int *t = NULL, mp = 2 * m +1, np = 2 * n + 1;
        int x,y,k,d;
        int count = 1;
        t = malloc(mp * np * sizeof *t);
        assert(t);
        for(y = k = 0; y < np ;++y){
            for(x = 0; x < mp; ++x){
                if((x & 1) && (y & 1))
                    t[y * mp + x] = k++;
                else
                    t[y * mp + x] = -1; 
            }

        }
        //Make a labyrinth randomly
        srand(time(NULL));
        while(count < (m * n)){

            if(myRand(2)){ // Up/Down separator 
                do{
                    x = myRand(m) * 2 + 1;
                    y = (myRand(n - 1) + 1) * 2;

                }while(t[(y - 1) * mp + x] == t[(y + 1) * mp + x]); /*Don't select the ones which are equal*/

                d = t[(y - 1) * mp + x] - t[(y + 1) * mp + x];
                //d selects the lowest one
                if(d > 0){
                    t[y * mp +x] = t[(y + 1) * mp + x];
                    spread(t[(y + 1) * mp +x],x,y-1,t,mp,&count);
                }

                else if(d < 0){
                    t[y * mp +x] = t[(y - 1) * mp + x];
                    spread(t[(y - 1) * mp +x],x,y+1,t,mp,&count);
                }   
            }
            else{   //Right/Left separator
                do{         
                    x = (myRand(m - 1) + 1) * 2;
                    y = myRand(n) * 2 + 1;

                }while(t[y * mp + x - 1] == t[y * mp + x + 1]);

                d = t[y * mp + x - 1] - t[y * mp + x + 1];

                if(d > 0){
                    t[y * mp +x] = t[y * mp + x + 1];
                    spread(t[y * mp + x + 1],x-1,y,t,mp,&count);
                }

                else if(d < 0){
                    t[y * mp +x] = t[y * mp +x - 1];
                    spread(t[y * mp + x - 1],x+1,y,t,mp,&count);
                }   
            }
        }   
        return t;
}
```